# Views how to group items with mutiple field collection fields

Tags: views, 8, entities

I can't figure how to group my content in my view.

Here is what I have, and what happen:
I have a content type "Slide" with the field "Body" a text (formatted) and a field collection called "Related content" that contains 2 fields ("Label", a simple text (plain) and "Related page", an entity reference).

I created 2 "Slide" with 2 "Related content" in each "Slide".

If I simply display "Body" and "Related content" I have each "Slide" displayed correctly, but the "Related Content" is a rendered list and I don't have access to the fields itself to rewrite the output (I want to create a link using the "Label" and the "Related page") like this:

Slide 1

- Label1
- Page 1
- Label 2
- Page 2

Slide 2

- Label 3
- Page 3
- Label 4
- Page 4

Now if I add a relationship to the field collection item, I do have access to the fields and I can rewrite the output, but now I have 1 slide for each item in the fields collection like this:

Slide 1
- Label1
Slide 1
- Label2
Slide 2
- Label3
Slide 2
- Label4

How do I keep the content grouped by Slide, and still display all the fields (not the rendered collection) so I can control the output.

Any help is welcome!